# Pycharm - SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x80'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8, pycharm

[image]

I am trying to open project in PyCharm which includes simple

virtual environment(python 3) and test.py

after opening it in PyCharm I've configured python interpreter to virtual environments Python 3.

then after running it in PyCharm I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x80' in file
>   /home/ubuntu/Downloads/PythonDemo/PythonDemo/venv_3/bin/python3 on
>   line 2, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

What you have entered as **Script:** looks like a Python interpreter. You should put `test.py` there. **Script parameters:** are the additional parameters passed to the script on the command line, *not* the Python script to run.

Answer (score 3):

Be cognizant of that you have right script path. Your file name must be same in the path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass required arguments at appropriate locations such as **script path, script parameters, interpreter, working directory** in the configurations, by clicking **Edit Configuration**s at top right position in pycharm. If you are not able to get particular python interpreter of your choice, you need to set it by adding interpreter option in bottom right in pycharm. Here is a snapshot of a script I was wishing to run with run/debug option.[image: example]